# Почему Presenter не пересоздается вместе с Activity

Tags: java, android

Не могу понять как работает MvpPresenter. Почему когда Activity пересоздается, то MvpPresenter все еще живет. Что из себя представляет MvpPresenter?

Потому что MvpPresenter использует SingleTone?

Comment: Без примера сложно будет ответить, ориентировачно - да, presenter не должен быть синглтоном, если только он не локальный, или у вас такое архитектурное решение

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, Вопрос в рамках Clean Architecture, я просто не знаю где взять материал чтобы понять данный подход. Гугл выдает непонятно что...А в исходниках не нашел ни SingleTone ничего другого....

Comment: Речь идет про Moxy?

Comment: @post_zeew, Да про нее

Answer (score 0):

Ваша активити наследуется от MvpAppCompatActivity(), так вот если посмотреть у нее метод onDestroy:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    getMvpDelegate().onDestroyView();

    if (isFinishing()) {
        getMvpDelegate().onDestroy();
    }
}
```

То мы увидим, что метод getMvpDelegate().onDestroy() вызывается только в том случае, когда активити финиширует (спокойно переживаем методы onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy() при перевороте к примеру). Заглянем глубже, в метод getMvpDelegate().onDestroy():

```
/**
 * <p>Destroy presenters.</p>
 */
public void onDestroy() {
    PresentersCounter presentersCounter = MvpFacade.getInstance().getPresentersCounter();
    PresenterStore presenterStore = MvpFacade.getInstance().getPresenterStore();

    Set<MvpPresenter> allChildPresenters = presentersCounter.getAll(mDelegateTag);
    for (MvpPresenter presenter : allChildPresenters) {
        boolean isRejected = presentersCounter.rejectPresenter(presenter, mDelegateTag);
        if (isRejected && presenter.getPresenterType() != PresenterType.GLOBAL) {
            presenterStore.remove(presenter.getTag());
            presenter.onDestroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Авторы библиотеки отметили нам его как "убийцу презентеров" :) Первым делом "boolean isRejected = " проверяется нет ли еще ссылок на этот презентер (мб мы инжектили его в несколько вьюшек), и если вернулось true и мы не объявляли презентер глобальным синглтоном, то презентер удаляется из стора и на нем самом вызывается метод onDestroy()
Надеюсь получилось объяснить хоть немножко :)

Comment: destroy presenters это скорей уничтожить презентеры, а не destroyer of presenters. кстати бул не проверяет ссылки, а просто проверяет если на нем флаг, для того чтоб его зачистить, скорей который аналогичным образом кладется в Set для Reject Ов ну это логично. Check reference это другая операция более низкого уровня

Comment: Другими словами Presenter живет в LifeCycle Activity? Поэтому при перевороте экрана, Presenter продолжает жить?

Comment: Зависит от жизненного цикла связанных с ним активити и фрагментов, если все активити, в которые был инжект презентера, финишировали и все фрагменты, в которые также мог быть инжект презентера, перешли в состояние isRemoving() (это что-то типо finish() у активити но не совсем так, в методе onDestroy() у MvpAppCompatFragment немного сложнее все), то тогда презентер удаляется из стора и дестроится